# How should I modify this back to back MOSFET AC mains circuit?

Tags: mosfet, ac, dimmer

I have a WiFi enabled AC mains light dimmer/switch that uses a back to back MOSFET design. The device sits in series with the load (lightbulb) and therefore does not have its own return/neutral connection.

I'd like some help to understand how its MOSFET / transistor arrangement works as I'm not fully confident I do understand how the control circuitry might be managing the MOSFETs and transistors so that:

- it always has power for itself (a tiny amount of current flows
  through the lightbulb at all times, but not enough to light it); and
- so that a controlled amount of current is allowed to flow through
  it when any level of light brightness is requested.

**Ultimately, what I'd like to do** is convert the device to be a user input device only (with minimal modifications to the circuit), connecting directly to the supply and neutral - by somehow disconnecting the path between the two side to prevent dead shorts when any level of light brightness is requested.

For example, could I do this simply by disconnecting the base of each transistor so that they're never open and therefore there is never a direct path between the two sides (i.e. pin 3).

This may seem like a pointless exercise/idea, but actually it would then give me a dimmer that I can use in software (over WiFi) as a user input to control other "smart" things such as mood scene selection.

[image]

Comment: If the transistor works as variable resistor, like you intend to make a dimmer, it would blow. The dimmer circuits use phase angle control or PWM.

Comment: Probably not something you should be messing with.. but what are the connections here... esp 1,2,3,4 and  5. maybe add those to the diagram

Comment: @MarkoBuršič it already is a working dimmer, I don't want it to be

Comment: @Trevor they're just the connections to the control circuitry which receives power for itself (5, 1, 2?), and controls the transistor base (3), I suspect (4) is a monitor. The control circuitry is where the WiFi radio and MCU live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disconnecting pin 3 from the control circuitry does the job, this prevents the transistors from opening up and therefore permanently prevents a low resistance path between the two AC sides.

Unless anybody can see any issues with that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a photovoltaic MOSFET driver like VOM1271  [link](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83469/vom1271t.pdf).

[image]

This is a MOSFET solid state relay .

Answer (score 0):

Your reverse-engineered circuit looks incomplete. I can't make sense of it.

The simplest thing to do would be to work out the minimum load required to keep the device working without modification. You then permanently wire a load resistor of that value into circuit.

If using a resistor rather than a lamp you need to allow adequate cooling - the same as you would for a tungsten light bulb.

This solution will waste a small amount of power. If you add an indicator lamp - a neon, for example - it will act as a reminder to turn the load off.

---

Another possible solution is to hook it up to a lower voltage supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3uNbF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Low-power setup.*

The device probably requires enough voltage and current to power up the internal circuitry. There may be a sweet spot at a lower voltage that will give enough power for the dimmer while minimising the load requirement. Try half-supply?

Comment: I had thought about adding a resistor in series with the mains connection (in place of what would normally be a lightbulb), that way I wouldn't actually need to make any modifications to the circuit at all. However, it need to be something about 1.2k (240v / 200mA) - thats 48w of heat to dissipate, in a small enclosed hole in the wall!

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 0):

I designed several back to back MOSFET dimmers. I am reasonably sure, that:
- the schematics has several mistakes. Please double-check your MOSFET gates schematics.
- point 5 is a connection to the control CPU's input, sensing the AC to get the Zero Detection
- point 1 is a connection to the control CPU's output, controlling each half-sine wave MOSFET switching PWM
- point 2 is digital ground

To achieve the MOSFETs to be off, their input must be a low (ground) signal from the control circuitry Before the 1kohm gate resistor pair.